# GUI not working after rewriting to MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface, swing

I'm practicing MVC style programming. I have a Mastermind game in a single file, working fine (maybe apart of the fact that "Check" button is invisible at start).

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/226726/

But when I've rewritten it to model, view, controller files - and when I click on empty Pin (that should be updated, and repainted with new color) - noting happens. Can anybody see any problems here ? I've tried placing repaint() in different places, but it simply does not work at all :/

Main :

```
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View("Mastermind", 400, 590, model);
        Controller controller = new Controller(model, view); 
        view.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Model :

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Model{
    static final int
    LINE = 5,
    SCORE = 10, OPTIONS = 20;
    Pin pins[][] = new Pin[21][LINE];
    int combination[] = new int[LINE];
    int curPin = 0;
    int turn = 1;
    Random generator = new Random();
    int repaintPin;
    boolean pinsRepaint=false;
    int pinsToRepaint;
    boolean isUpdate = true, isPlaying = true, isRowFull = false;
    static final int HIT_X[] = {270,290,310,290,310}, HIT_Y[] = {506,496,496,516,516};

    public Model(){

        for ( int i=0; i < SCORE; i++ ){
            for ( int j = 0; j < LINE; j++ ){
                pins[i][j] = new Pin(20,0);
                pins[i][j].setPosition(j*50+30,510-i*50);
                pins[i+SCORE][j] = new Pin(8,0);
                pins[i+SCORE][j].setPosition(HIT_X[j],HIT_Y[j]-i*50);
            }
        }
        for ( int i=0; i < LINE; i++ ){
            pins[OPTIONS][i] = new Pin( 20, i+2 );
            pins[OPTIONS][i].setPosition( 370,i * 50 + 56);
        }

    }

    void fillHole(int color) {
        pins[turn-1][curPin].setColor(color+1);
        pinsRepaint = true;
        pinsToRepaint = turn;
        curPin = (curPin+1) % LINE;
        if (curPin == 0){
            isRowFull = true;
        }
        pinsRepaint = false;
        pinsToRepaint = 0;
    }

    void check() {
        int junkPins[] = new int[LINE], junkCode[] = new int[LINE];
        int pinCount = 0, pico = 0;

        for ( int i = 0; i < LINE; i++ ) {
            junkPins[i] = pins[turn-1][i].getColor();
            junkCode[i] = combination[i];
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < LINE; i++ ){
            if (junkPins[i]==junkCode[i]) {
                pins[turn+SCORE][pinCount].setColor(1);
                pinCount++;
                pico++;
                junkPins[i] = 98;
                junkCode[i] = 99;
            }
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < LINE; i++ ){
            for ( int j = 0; j < LINE; j++ )
                if (junkPins[i]==junkCode[j]) {
                    pins[turn+SCORE][pinCount].setColor(2);
                    pinCount++;
                    junkPins[i] = 98;
                    junkCode[j] = 99;
                    j = LINE;
            }
        }
        pinsRepaint = true;
        pinsToRepaint = turn + SCORE;
        pinsRepaint = false;
        pinsToRepaint=0;

        if ( pico == LINE ){
            isPlaying = false;
        }
        else if ( turn >= 10 ){
                isPlaying = false;
        }
        else{
            curPin = 0;
            isRowFull = false;
            turn++;
        }
    }

    void combination() {
        for ( int i = 0; i < LINE; i++ ){
          combination[i] = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
        }
    }
}

class Pin{
    private int color, X, Y, radius;

    public Pin(){
        X = 0; Y = 0; radius = 0; color = 0;
    }

    public Pin( int r,int c ){
        X = 0; Y = 0; radius = r; color = c;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return X;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return Y;
    }

    public int getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int r){
        radius = r;
    }

    public void setPosition( int x,int y ){
        this.X = x ;
        this.Y = y ;
    }
    public void setColor( int c ){
        color = c;
    }
    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

View:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class View extends Frame{  
    Model model;
    JButton checkAnswer;
    private JPanel button;
    private static final Color COLORS[] = {Color.black, Color.white, Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.blue, new Color(7, 254, 250)};

    public View(String name, int w, int h, Model m){
        model = m;
        setTitle( name );
        setSize( w,h );
        setResizable( false );
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        button = new JPanel();
        button.setSize( new Dimension(400, 100));
        button.setVisible(true);
        checkAnswer = new JButton("Check");
        checkAnswer.setSize( new Dimension(200, 30));
        button.add( checkAnswer );
        this.add( button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        button.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint( Graphics g ) {
        g.setColor( new Color(238, 238, 238));
        g.fillRect( 0,0,400,590);

        for ( int i=0; i < model.pins.length; i++ ) {
            paintPins(model.pins[i][0],g);
            paintPins(model.pins[i][1],g);
            paintPins(model.pins[i][2],g);
            paintPins(model.pins[i][3],g);
            paintPins(model.pins[i][4],g);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update( Graphics g ) {
        if ( model.isUpdate ) {
            paint(g);
        }
        else {
            model.isUpdate = true;
            paintPins(model.pins[model.repaintPin-1][0],g);
            paintPins(model.pins[model.repaintPin-1][1],g);
            paintPins(model.pins[model.repaintPin-1][2],g);
            paintPins(model.pins[model.repaintPin-1][3],g);
            paintPins(model.pins[model.repaintPin-1][4],g);
        }
    }

    void repaintPins( int pin ) {
        model.repaintPin = pin;
        model.isUpdate = false;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintPins(Pin p, Graphics g ){
        int X = p.getX();
        int Y = p.getY();
        int color = p.getColor();
        int radius = p.getRadius();
        int x = X-radius;
        int y = Y-radius;

        if (color > 0){
            g.setColor( COLORS[color]);
            g.fillOval( x,y,2*radius,2*radius );
        }
        else{
            g.setColor( new Color(238, 238, 238) );
            g.drawOval( x,y,2*radius-1,2*radius-1 );
        }
        g.setColor( Color.black );
        g.drawOval( x,y,2*radius,2*radius );
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Controller implements MouseListener, ActionListener { 
    private Model model;
    private View view;

    public Controller(Model m, View v){ 
        model = m;
        view = v;

        view.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        } });
        view.addMouseListener(this);
        view.checkAnswer.addActionListener(this);
        model.combination();
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
        if(e.getSource() == view.checkAnswer){
            if(model.isRowFull){
                model.check();
            }
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Point mouse = new Point();

        mouse = e.getPoint();
        if (model.isPlaying){
            if (mouse.x > 350) {
                int button = 1 + (int)((mouse.y - 32) / 50);
                if ((button >= 1) && (button <= 5)){
                    model.fillHole(button);
                    if(model.pinsRepaint){
                        view.repaintPins( model.pinsToRepaint );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)  {}
}
```

Comment: Both the old and new code have problems related to mixing AWT and Swing components. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687871

Comment: so the problem with no update may be caused by that ?

Comment: Yes. http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/

Comment: I've added and example that may guide your redesign.

Answer (score 159):

As you've discovered, the [Model–View–Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) pattern is no panacea, but it offers some advantages. Rooted in [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller), the Swing separable model architecture is discussed in [*A Swing Architecture Overview*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html). Based on [this outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687871), the following example shows an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) implementation of a much simpler game that illustrates similar principles. Note that the `Model` manages a single `Piece`, chosen at random. In response to a user's selection, the `View` invokes the `check()` method, while listening for a response from the `Model` via `update()`. The `View` then updates itself using information obtained from the `Model`. Similarly, the `Controller` may `reset()` the `Model`. In particular, there is no drawing in the `Model` and no game logic in the `View`. This somewhat more complex [game](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) was designed to illustrate the same concepts.

Addendum: I've modified the original example to show how [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) allows one to enhance the `View` without changing the nature of the `Model`.

Addendum: As @akf observes, [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) hinges on the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Your `Model` needs a way to notify the `View` of changes. Several approaches are widely used:

- In the example below, `Model` extends [`Observable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) for simplicity.
- A more common approach uses an [`EventListenerList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html), as shown in the [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) application and suggested by the large number of [`EventListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html) subinterfaces and implementing classes.
- A third option is to use a [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533581).

Addendum: Some common questions about Swing controllers are addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25556585/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23416515/230513).

[image: screen capture]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3066590/230513
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274962
 */
public class MVCGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new MVCGame()::display);
    }

    public void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MainPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

final class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    public MainPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View(model);
        Control control = new Control(model, view);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Guess what color!", JLabel.CENTER);
        this.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(control.createPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}

/**
 * Control panel
 */
final class Control {

    private final Model model;
    private final View view;
    private final JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");

    public Control(Model model, View view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(reset);
        reset.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
        return panel;
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
            if ("Reset".equals(cmd)) {
                model.reset();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * View
 */
final class View extends JPanel {

    private static final String PROMPT = "Click a button.";
    private final Model model;
    private final ColorIcon icon = new ColorIcon(80, Color.gray);
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel(PROMPT, icon, JLabel.CENTER);

    public View(Model model) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        this.model = model;
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        this.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(genButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        model.addObserver(new ModelObserver());
    }

    private JPanel genButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        for (Piece p : Piece.values()) {
            PieceButton pb = new PieceButton(p);
            pb.addActionListener(new ButtonHandler());
            panel.add(pb);
        }
        return panel;
    }

    private class ModelObserver implements Observer {

        @Override
        public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
            if (arg == null) {
                label.setText(PROMPT);
                icon.color = Color.gray;
            } else {
                if ((Boolean) arg) {
                    label.setText("Win!");
                } else {
                    label.setText("Keep trying.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            PieceButton pb = (PieceButton) e.getSource();
            icon.color = pb.piece.color;
            label.repaint();
            model.check(pb.piece);
        }
    }

    private final static class PieceButton extends JButton {

        private Piece piece;

        public PieceButton(Piece piece) {
            this.piece = piece;
            this.setIcon(new ColorIcon(16, piece.color));
        }
    }

    private static class ColorIcon implements Icon {

        private final int size;
        private Color color;

        public ColorIcon(int size, Color color) {
            this.size = size;
            this.color = color;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return size;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Model
 */
class Model extends Observable {

    private static final Random rnd = new Random();
    private static final Piece[] pieces = Piece.values();
    private Piece hidden = init();

    private Piece init() {
        return pieces[rnd.nextInt(pieces.length)];
    }

    public void reset() {
        hidden = init();
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void check(Piece guess) {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(guess.equals(hidden));
    }
}

enum Piece {

    Red(Color.red), Green(Color.green), Blue(Color.blue);
    public Color color;

    private Piece(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: @trevor_nise: I've updated the example above. You may find it useful to compare the revisions.

Comment: For anyone that's curious Fowler put up the following article in 2006: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SeparatedPresentation.html

Comment: See also [*Java SE Application Design With MVC*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html).

Comment: What is the reason for these classes extending JFrame ?

Comment: Great answer, 
but it seems a little weird to me a Controller inheriting JPanel and being added to the main panel. Isn't the controller supposed to be something logical and thus not visible?
What am I missing?

Comment: @miguelcobain: Good observation; I wanted to illustrate how the controller may alter both the view and model via a separate implementation of the pattern in which the button combines a view and model. `Control` overrides no methods of `JPanel`, so a static factory might be better.

Comment: controller shouldn't need to call view.reset explicitly: calling model.reset will notify the view, or not? (Guilty of not running the example :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: Good eye! Careless re-factoring on my part in [r8](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3072979/revisions). I've updated the example accordingly and reverted to a single listing for easier running.

Comment: +1 Before this, I hadn't seen a fully working example of a Swing app using MVC. Kudos. It has inspired me to rewrite the same app in an alternate MVP architecture. For those interested in comparing/contrasting, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22032787/1438660

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for this thorough example (you linked me here from a recent question of mine). I've understood quite some things a lot better. However, I remain confused about *why* the `Control` class needs a reference to `view`. To me it seems `Control` only contains the button to reset the `model`; it doesn't use the `view` reference at all. Couldn't this be integrated into the View, since it contains UI elements?

Comment: @MHaaZ: Possibly; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687871) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25556585/230513).

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for the great example. A couple of questions: I can't see why the `View` class is specially called a View (as in MVC). Is it because it's the only one observing the model? The `JLabel` _"Click a button."_ and the `Control` class are views too, all nested into the `MainPanel` which is a View too I believe (assuming the MVC model supports nested views).

Comment: @trashgod Another question is about the grouping of components into Views. Why is the View class composed of an icon, a label which displays the move outcome messages and a button panel, while the ControlPanel is composed of only a Reset button? Shouldn't the button panel belong to ControlPanel as well, making up a true 'control panel' with controls? If on the other hand ControlPanel is a controller, why does it handle the Reset button only and not the choosing of a color button?

Comment: As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25556585/230513), "not _every_ interaction needs to pass through your application's controller." As note [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-not-working-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979?noredirect=1#comment20904975_3072979), the example illustrates how a controller may listen to the view, as shown in this  [diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687871/230513).

Answer (score 20):

When looking through Swing, one way that the designers consistently employ updating of View components in its MVC implementation is through Observer/Observable callbacks.  An example can be seen in the `AbstractTableModel`, which has a variety of `fireTable*Changed/Updated/etc` methods that will alert all of its `TableModelListener` observers of mods to the model.

One option you have is to add a listener type to your `Model` class, and then notify your registered observers of any mods to the state of your model.  Your `View` should be a listener, and it should repaint itself upon receipt of an update.

EDIT: +1 to trashgod.  consider this an alternate wording to his explanation.