# Swing - how to handle multiple cross-dependent components?

Tags: java, swing

This is a more general question: 
I have a quite complicated files table in swing (the data model is not trivial) , and when when the user clicks on an entry , two other view components need to change - File statistics view , and the file content view - both on the same screen.

One options is to have all these components class definitions in the same file , and then have the reference each other - But this will make a very messy code.

The other option I could think of is to pass the statistics and content components to the table object , and have him use it - but that will render the table not - reusable anywhere else.

I'm sure there's a better way to do it - what would you recommend to do?

Option 1:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel{

private MyTable table;
private MyFileViewer fv;
private MyFileStats stats;

class MyTable {
   addMouseListener({ ... fv.update(); stats.update(); })
}
class MyFileViewer{...}
class MyFileStats{...}
}
```

Options 2:

```
class MyTable {

   MyTable(MyFileViewer fv, MyFileStats stats) { ... 
       addMouseListener({fv.update, stats.update ... } 
   }    
}
```

Comment: By "...have all these components defined in the same file" do you mean have their class definitions in the same java file, or just have them instantiated there (ex, you simply call new FileStatsVeiw and new FileContentView)?

Comment: Maybe some quick pseudo code for the two options you're considering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 3: The [Model–View–Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) pattern, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979) and in [this outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687871). [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) hinges on the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Instead of having each view update the others, arrange for each view to register itself as a listener to your data model. When the model changes, each view updates itself accordingly.

Comment: +1 for using events.  Using events helps build low coupled highly cohesive code.  You could also sprinkle in Mediators as needed to route your events as needed.