# inclusion/exclusion on toroid plane using java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I wrote a program to solve the following:

> Implement a diffusion limited aggregation simulation on a toroid plane where seeds are randomly created, and particles move randomly. they move if they particles do not land near a seed or a particle. where user inputs seeds (red pixels), particles (black pixels), steps (no or iterations), plane size.

My code is very slow. How can I make it faster?

I randomly created x and y coordinates and drew  red pixels (seeds), then randomly  created x and y for black pixels (particles), if a black pixel lands where there is a red or black pixel it can stay, otherwise it moves randomly again until there are no more particles . If the pixel lands out of borders like  x > border then x=0; if x <1 then x= border. The same for y.

This just means that if it lands on the border I move it to the opposite border.  Then checks for the neighboring pixels again. I have an outer loop to create the seeds, and inner loop for the particles. In the inner loop I check for the x,y positions:

```
//Place, move, and "stick" the particles; stop if either steps or particles = 0
for (int p = 0; p < particles; p++) {

    for (int s = 0; s < steps; s++) {
        if (xPos > image.getWidth() ) {
                       do something
                    } 
        else if (xPos < 1) {
                        do something
                    }
        if (yPos > image.getHeight() - 2) {
                         do something
                    } 
        else if (yPos < 1) {
                         do something
                    } 
        else if (xPos > image.getWidth() && yPos > image.getHeight()) {
                         do something
                    } 
        else if (xPos < 1 && yPos < 1) {
                         do something
                    }

     //If the surrounding pixels' color is not white, make that particle stick.
            if (moveValid()) {
                image.setRGB(xPos, yPos, 0xFF000000);
            } 


            //Otherwise, move in a random direction
            else {
                if(xPos == 1 && image.getRGB(size - 2, yPos) != 0xFFFFFFFF){
                   draw(xPos,yPos);
                }
                else if(xPos == size - 2 && image.getRGB(1,yPos) != 0xFFFFFFFF){
                    draw(xPos,yPos);
                }
                if(yPos == 1 && image.getRGB(xPos, size - 2) != 0xFFFFFFFF){
                   draw(xPos,yPos);
                }
                else if(yPos == size - 2 && image.getRGB(xPos,1) != 0xFFFFFFFF){
                    draw(xPos,yPos);
                }
                else {
                    move();

                }


            }
        }

        //Regenerate random x and y positions for the next particle   
        xPos = random.nextInt(size);
        yPos = random.nextInt(size);
    }
```

Comment: 1) I would replace `image.getWidth()`  & `getHeight()` to `int` attributes declared outside the outer `for` loop.  2) Great benefits can be had from calling for the byte array of the image and making all changes directly to that array.  3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 4) Is this [tag:homework]? If so, it is advantageous to tag it as such.

Comment: What does your [profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) say?

Answer (score 2):

Although the implementation of `draw()` is not shown, it looks like you're updating a `BufferedImage` and then rendering it.

1. The first step is always to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) your existing code, looking for easily implemented optimizations.
2. The second step is sometimes to set aside the existing code and try a different approach.

You may be able to leverage the Mode-View-Controller pattern, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687871/230513) and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513). In particular, let your [DLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation) *model* evolve on a background thread at full speed, while updating your *view* at a more sustainable rate. This [article](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/threadwatch) suggests several approaches to synchronization and includes a related example that uses `javax.swing.Timer` to pace the updates.