# Using BorderLayout for adding 4 in-line Components to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border-layout

In my application, there are 4 panels. And i need to insert them into the main panel, which uses `BorderLayout`. The 4 panels are...

1. A thin Image strip.
2. 4 buttons just below above
3. A TextField covering the complete page.
4. An about at end.

This is my code...

```
    add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(about, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

When I do this, the `buttonPanel` disappears. How can I achieve what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually try to keep a maximum of 3 components in any `BorderLayout`, so I would do it like this...

```
JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel innerPanel= new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

innerPanel.add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
innerPanel.add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
innerPanel.add(about, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

outerPanel.add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
outerPanel.add(innerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

As long as you keep the 'maximum-stretched' component in the `CENTER` (in this case, your `logScrollPane`) then it'll always work. If you want to use the panel, such as setting it on a `JFrame`, just use `add(outerPanel)`.

Don't be afraid of `BorderLayout` - the ability of this layout to auto-expand the `CENTER` component to fill the available space make it a very powerful and very important `LayoutManager`!

Comment: Thanks :). Swing does take a toll. There should be an mvc like framework to make applciation quickly. Netbeans GUI is still a major help

Comment: @Jatin: See also this [MVC outline](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2687871/230513) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).