# Is it proper to update a tree node using `nodeChanged`

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree` and a `JTextField`. When I select a node on the tree, the text field will display the value of the node. I can then edit the text and save it to change the selected node's value. I use the `DefaultTreeModel`'s `nodeChanged` method to update the tree.

Is this a proper way to tell the tree model to update its node? To me it looks ugly because I'm explicitly accessing the tree's model and telling it that something has happened.

Here's some code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class TextPaneTest extends JFrame {

    private JTextField textBox = null;
    private JTree tree = null;
    private JButton button = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TextPaneTest();
    }

    public TextPaneTest() {

        // Main panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Panel holding tree
        JPanel treePanel = new JPanel();
        treePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Panel holding text field and button

        JPanel editPanel = new JPanel();
        editPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // My textbox
        textBox = new JTextField();

        // button
        button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Save changes");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                String text = textBox.getText();
                node.setUserObject(text);
                DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
                model.nodeChanged(node);
            }
        });

        // My Tree
        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");
        tree = new JTree(top);
        tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent evt) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                textBox.setText(node.getUserObject().toString());
        }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        // Add tree
        treePanel.add(scrollPane);
        panel.add(treePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Add box and button to edit panel
        editPanel.add(textBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        editPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Add edit panel
        panel.add(editPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Add everything to the frame
        this.add(panel);
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From poking around the JavaDoc and code for DefaultTreeModel and DefaultMutableTreeNode, I think what you are doing is ok.  If you had changed the structure of the model (say by removing a node) then you would not need to call anything on the model, since the TreeModel would know that you did something to it.  However, in this case, you are changing the contents of a node that the model references.  So it seems reasonable that you would have to inform the TreeModel that the contents of one of its nodes is now different.

I may be missing something myself, but I think what you have is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness: it might *look* slightly less ugly if you updated the node exclusively via model api

```
TreePath selected = tree.getSelectionPath();
tree.getModel().valueForPathChanged(selected, textBox.getText());
```

Comment: For some reason, that worked where `nodeChanged()` didn't (I have a specific `TreeCellRenderer`, I don't know if it makes a difference...).
In any case, +1! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your example appears correct. Expanding on @matt's correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19432670/230513), this MVC [illustration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687871/230513) may offer some insight. Because the `JTree` view also allows editing, it may invoke methods of the model. The model in turn notifies all listeners, including the tree itself, by invoking `fireTreeNodesChanged()` on you behalf. To see the effect, add *another* listener:

```
tree.getModel().addTreeModelListener(new TreeModelListener() {
    @Override
    public void treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
        update(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void treeNodesInserted(TreeModelEvent e) {
        update(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void treeNodesRemoved(TreeModelEvent e) {
        update(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void treeStructureChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
        update(e);
    }

    private void update(TreeModelEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
});
```

Additional notes:

- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Instead of using `setSize()`, override the tree panel's [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) method and `pack()` the enclosing frame.

  ```
  JPanel treePanel = new JPanel(){

      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(300, 200);
      }
  };
  …
  this.pack();
  ```